# If $p(x) =x^4 - x^3 +px^2 -4x +q$, find $p$ and $q$ if $p(0)=3$ and $p(-1)=11$

Tags: polynomials

If $p(x) =x^4 - x^3 +px^2 -4x +q$, find $p$ and $q$ if $p(0)=3$ and $p(-1)=11$

Can someone please teach me how to do this question? thanks

Comment: I don't think it's a great idea to use $\,p\,$ to denote two rather different things...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the values x= 0 and x= -1 in p(x).

p(0) = q= 3.

Now put x=-1 then find another value.

Comment: hmm I got 9? the answer says its 2

Comment: don't worry I got it thanks!