# If $p(x)=ax^3 -2x^2 +bx+c$, find $a, b$ and $c$ if $p(0)=12$, $p(-1)=3$ and $p(2)=36$

Tags: polynomials

If $p(x)=ax^3 -2x^2 +bx+c$, find $a, b$ and $c$ if $p(0)=12$,  $p(-1)=3$ and $p(2)=36$

Can someone please teach me how to do this question thanks!

[image]

Comment: What did you try? What does $p(0)=12$ mean?

Comment: I guess this is urgent :)

Comment: well, this question is from my text book. The concept I get from this is that you have to substitute the values into the polynomial. Although I have and I've only found c so far which is 12.

Comment: This is basically the same question as the [other one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444794/if-px-x4-x3-px2-4x-q-find-p-and-q-if-p0-3-and-p-1-11) you posted.

Comment: Doing all those substitutions turns this into a problem in linear algebra (a system of linear equations). Can you solve those?

Comment: @m_l for some reason I tried the exact same thing as previous and it dosnt work...

Comment: Show your work then, and someone will spot the error, I'm sure!

Comment: ok will do. ill post it on this thread

Comment: Nothing wrong so far. You haven't used $p(2)=36$ up to now.

Comment: Ok, and now if you plug in $x=2$, what will you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $p(2)=36$ , you'll have
$8a - 8 + 2b + 12 = 36$.
Simplify it, you'll get $4a+b=16$.
Together with the equation you've written down,

$a=3$,$b=4$

Answer (score 1):

This is really a problem in basic linear algebra.  If we simply plug in the three given values of the independent variable $x$, we obtain the three equations for $a$, $b$, $c$:

$p(0) = 12$ becomes

$c = 12$;

$p(-1) = 3$ becomes

$-a -b +c = 5$;

$p(2) = 36$ becomes

$8a + 2b + c = 44$;

looks like we get $c$ for free!  Plugging $c= 12$ into the second and third equations yields

$-a -b = -7$;

$8a + 2b = 32$;

looks like we get

$6a = 18$,

$a = 3$;

and finally,

$b= 4$.

This method actually generalizes to arbitrary polynomials; the powers of the different values of $x$ form a matrix and the coefficients form a vector; the rest is *clearly* linear algabra.  Glad to be of assistance in this matter.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

So, you already found out that $c=12$. You also showed that $-a-b+10=3$, which we can simplify to $-a-b=-7$.

Doing a similar substitution,
$$a(2)^3-2(2)^2+b(2)+c=36.$$

The arithmetic is not too difficult:
$$8a-8+2b+c=36.$$

We can definitely move that $-8$ over, and remember how we already found out that $c=12$? Let's substitute that too:
$$8a+2b+12=44.$$

Now for the 12:
$$\color{blue}{8a+2b}=\color{blue}{32}.$$

This is good. Remember how we said that $-a-b=-7$? Let's just multiply that by $2$:
$$\color{red}{-2a-2b}=\color{red}{-14}.$$

Now check this out: if we add these two previous equations together, the $b$-terms will cancel (i.e., $2b-2b=0$):
$$\color{blue}{8a+2b}\color{red}{-2a-2b}=\color{blue}{32}\color{red}{-14}$$

or
$$6a=18.$$

From here, it is very easy to find $a$, and now that you have two of the three variables, finding $b$ should be very easy after a bit of substitution. I hope this helps.